# Java. Как считать несколько значений с клавиатуры и преобразовать их в числа?

Tags: java

Учусь.
Необходимо преобразовать несколько последовательно введенных значений в числа. Есть вот такой код, но он избыточен. Как его ужать и упростить?

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String a = reader.readLine();
    String b = reader.readLine();
    String c = reader.readLine();
    int numA = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int numB = Integer.parseInt(b);
    int numC = Integer.parseInt(c);
```

Comment: Используйте [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: не могли бы дать более развернутый комментарий?

Comment: Уточните формат данных.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numA = scan.nextInt();
    int numB = scan.nextInt();
    int numC = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(numA + " " + numB + " " + numC);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int numA = scanner.nextInt();
```

**UPDATE:** Веселья ради вариант со стримами, доступный с Java 9

```
List<Integer> ints = new Scanner(System.in)
                           .tokens()
                           .limit(3)
                           .map(Integer::valueOf)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: а как добавить возможно ввода поочередно нескольких значений через "Enter" с автоматическим присвоением введенрго числа переменной??

Comment: Три раза повторить последнюю строчку моего ответа, например.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто немного модифицировать Ваш код:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int numA = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int numB = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int numC = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
```